# awk pipe matched contents

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have use awk、grep use pipe get the contents we called A(part of contents in my file)：

```
LOC_Os04g47290
LOC_Os04g53190,LOC_Os04g53195
LOC_Os09g20260
```

I want to use the contents to grep or get matched contents and others in B(part of contents in my file)：

```
_O2 int381,int382,int384,int385,int386,int387,int388,int391,int392,int393,int394,int395,int396,int397,int398,int399,int400,int401,int402,int403,int404,int408,int409,int410,int412,int413,int414:chr4:31119012..31944575    chr4:31669055..31674598 LOC_Os04g53190,LOC_Os04g53195   CPuORF12,expressed - conserved peptide uORF-containing transcript, expressed ; protein ;        PF01593 Amino_oxidase   0.0539946
```

when I use

```
cat a|awk -F"," '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'|grep -f - B|grep PF|awk '{print $4"\t"$(NF-2)}'
```

i will get

```
LOC_Os04g53190,LOC_Os04g53195   PF01593
```

But, i want to print

```
  LOC_Os04g53190 PF01593
  LOC_Os04g53195 PF01593
```

Comment: Don't post code as images, it's not searchable and we can't copy/paste it into answers

Comment: Your question is not clear. Just what exactly is your difficulty? What have you tried so far?, Which is your input and expected output?

Comment: sorry,I have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Improving `awk` last statement

```
cat a | 
awk -F"," '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' | 
grep -f - B | 
grep PF | 
awk '{n=split($4,v,","); for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) print v[i]"\t"$(NF-2)}'
```

you get,

```
LOC_Os04g53190  PF01593
LOC_Os04g53195  PF01593
```

**bonus: awk only solution**

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{d[$1]; next}
    $(NF-2) ~ /^PF/{
        n=split($4,v,",")
        for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) if(v[i] in d) print v[i]"\t"$(NF-2)
    }
' RS="[\n,]" a RS="\n" B
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample file**

```
sharad$ cat sample_file
foo
bar
sharad$
```

**Capture matching contents into a variable**

```
sharad$ match=$(cat sample_file | grep foo)
```

**Capture non-matching contents into another variable**

```
sharad$ non_match=$(cat sample_file | grep -v foo)
sharad$
```

**Verify the contents of matching and non-matching variables (grep -v)**

```
sharad$ echo $match
foo
sharad$ echo $non_match
bar
sharad$
```

**From man grep**

-v, --invert-match
         Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.

Comment: `cat` is not needed here, could be just `grep 'foo' sample_file`, see https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/useless-use-of-cat/

Comment: Agree :) I used cat just to align with the question which states that the o/p is piped to grep.